# Can not read Excel File using NuGet FileHelpers.ExcelNPOIStorage

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, filehelpers

I have a problem with reading file using ExcelNPOIStorage.
Error Code:

> System.MissingFieldException: 'Field not found: 'NPOI.SS.UserModel.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK'.'

Code:

```
var filesList = "test.xlsx";
string folderPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\SyncFiles");
string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, file);

                        if (File.Exists(filePath))
                        {
                        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

                        var provider = new ExcelNPOIStorage(typeof(Mac))
                                {
                                    StartRow = 2,
                                    StartColumn = 1,
                                    FileName = filePath,
                                    SheetName = "Sheet1"
                            };

                                var res = (Mac[])provider.ExtractRecords();
}
```

Mac Class:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
    class Mac
    {

        public int PropertyID;

        public string ID;

        public string Name;
    }
```

test.xlsx

[image]

Comment: Sounds like your model needs some attributes https://www.filehelpers.net/example/MissingValues/MissingValuesFieldNullValue/

Comment: any suggestion  which attributes for given file 3 columns and 5 rows ?